# wp_nav_menu not displaying on single post page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using Twentytwelve theme and everything is fine but navigation menu is not displaying in single post page whereas the navigation menus are displaying in every other page. This is the snippet I am using in *header.php* to display menu.

```
    wp_nav_menu( array(  
       'theme_location'  => 'primary', 
       'menu_class'      => 'nav-menu',
       'container_class' => '',
       'container'       => false,
       'fallback_cb'     => false  ) 
    );
```

Comment: in single.php check which header is being called? and put your code on that file too

Comment: I have done get_header() call in *single.php* and I had also once checked using the code of header.php instead of get_header().

Comment: so when you are going to the details page of a post the menu is not getting displayed? you did get_header() in the single .php?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I did get_header() call in *single.php*.

Comment: can you post the single.php code

Comment: Please have a look on this link for the code: [link](https://gist.github.com/prajwalstha123/5511d8313dc4fb2761814c5f28458c9b)

Comment: the single.php is ok, can you show header.php

Comment: Please have a look on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/prajwalstha123/d4e8655f434fda216501ed759595b1f4)

Comment: yup, everything is ok in both the files, i guess you are not visiting a single page, thus the confusion, try to visit  a post link from wpadmin but clicking on edit post and the the link it has, check if you can see\

Comment: Can you please tell me what exactly it is showing instead of primary menu? If you can provide a screenshot that would be good to understand.

Comment: I think the post detail page for the posts you are check is not rendering through single.php file because everything seems correct. Check any other file in your theme like single-postname.php.

Comment: The navigation menu's HTML are missing. I am pretty sure that the page template being rendered in *single.php* as I have checked using echo basename(__FILE__); in the page template. And When I check using if(has_nav_menu()) it returns false for the single post page but returns true for other pages.

Comment: Here are the screenshots:
Case 1 (When menu is being rendered in other pages): http://prntscr.com/fbffhf

Case 2 (When menu is not being rendered in single post page):
http://prntscr.com/fbffxl

Comment: Do you have hosted it? Screenshot does not make difference to understand which one is single? except your comment.

Comment: Just check at your detail page by inspecting elements using firebug. What is missing, may be your menu are there but not showing due to css. It will be more clear to us if you also share screen-shot of that.

Comment: Here are the screenshot of the inspector console:
Case 1 ( When there is not menu ): http://prntscr.com/fbfkou
Case 2 (When there is menu ): http://prntscr.com/fbfl6e

Comment: Can you please share the full inspect window where we can see the body classes too.

Comment: Let me share the URL of the site:
Single Post Page: http://rubiconmigration.com.au/457-visa-information-changes/
Other Page: http://rubiconmigration.com.au/

Comment: Try this : wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); once and check

Comment: I did this too. I just want to know if there are any kind of query that is forcing navigation menu not to display in the single post page. As I have found out that this type of issues comes for archive page in some cases.

Comment: There is nothing such done in the theme, I have tried in my local and everything was perfect.

Comment: I have found the issue. One of the plugin used on the site is forcing the nav menu to hide. When I deactivated the plugin. It automatically get displayed.